# Arbitrary Sprockets asset path in assets only gem for Rails/Sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm trying to make and distribute a Ruby Gem where I package CoffeeScript files for use in other applications.

It works fine in most Sprockets apps, but when I try to include it in a Rails App I get:

```
undefined method `append_path' for Sprockets:Module
```

The error is from this line:

```
::Sprockets.append_path File.join(root_dir, "source")
```

How come when using the gem in a Rails app Sprockets has no append_path method? Is there a way to get Rails apps look in a specific directory for asset files?

I don't want to put my files in app/assets/javascripts because this is an assets only app and burying them like that just to accomodate Rails is aesthetically displeasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  config.paths['app/assets'] = "source"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of rails are you using.
Sprockets has been included in rails.

check out 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Rails 3.2.11. The Sprockets module exists, but it doesn't respond to append_path like it does in Sprockets apps outside of Rails.